# Merge list by dictionary key and sum values if key is same

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary like this:

```py
# sample data
data = [
    [
        {'id': '1', 'value': '10', 'name': 'abc'},
        {'id': '2', 'value': '5', 'name': 'def'},
        {'id': '3', 'value': '15', 'name': 'ghi'},
        {'id': '4', 'value': '20', 'name': 'jkl'},
        # ... many
    ],
    [
        {'id': '2', 'value': '5', 'name': 'def'},
        {'id': '3', 'value': '5', 'name': 'ghijkl'},
        # ... many
    ],
    [
        {'id': '4', 'value': '10', 'name': 'test'},
        # ... many
    ],
    # ... many
]
```

Now I want to loop through all data, and add values if the `id` is same, and merge back to single list.

```py
# sample output
[
    {'id': '1', 'value': '10', 'name': 'abc'}, # there is no id 1 in other array so the value remain same, but name from the first item
    {'id': '2', 'value': '10', 'name': 'def'}, # same id found in another array so add value, but name from the first item
    {'id': '3', 'value': '20', 'name': 'ghi'}, # same id found in another array so add value, but name from the first item
    {'id': '4', 'value': '30', 'name': 'jkl'}, # same id found in another array so add value, but name from the first item
]

# name should be always pick from the first item of list.
```

How can I achieve that?

This is what I've done so far with the help of @Manlai:

```py
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for lst in data:
    for d in lst:
        count += Counter({d['id']:int(d['value'])})
out = [dict(zip(('id','value'), map(str, pair))) for pair in count.items()]
```

Comment: How does your code not work exactly? In essence, what's your actual question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I need the logic to process(convert) that input data into output. I've tried on my own, but I was unable to find solution.

Comment: Show what you tried and explain how it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`. First, iterate over `data` and create dictionaries from `id`-`value` pairs. Then cast these dictionaries to `collections.Counter` and add these counters.

Finally, unpack the counter back into a list of dictionaries.

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
names = {}
for lst in data:
    for d in lst:
        if d['id'] not in names:
            names[d['id']] = d['name']
        count += Counter({d['id']:int(d['value'])})
    
out = []
for Id, total in count.items():
    out.append({'id': Id, 'value': str(total), 'name': names[Id]})
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'value': '10', 'name': 'abc'},
 {'id': '2', 'value': '10', 'name': 'def'},
 {'id': '3', 'value': '20', 'name': 'ghi'},
 {'id': '4', 'value': '30', 'name': 'jkl'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary dictionary to accumulate the values into a single instance of dictionary for each common identifier.  Then use the values of that temporary dictionary as your output:

```
tally = dict()              # temporary dictionary
for dl in data:             # go through sub-lists
    for d in dl:            # go through dictionaries
        key = d['id']       # get common identifier
        if key not in tally:
            tally[key] = d.copy()   # add entry for identifier
            tally[key]['value'] = 0 # initialize value as numeric
        tally[key]['value'] += int(d['value']) # sum values

out = list(tally.values())  # convert values to final list

print(out)
[{'id': '1', 'value': 10, 'name': 'abc'}, 
 {'id': '2', 'value': 10, 'name': 'def'}, 
 {'id': '3', 'value': 20, 'name': 'ghi'}, 
 {'id': '4', 'value': 30, 'name': 'jkl'}]
```